# Can I install "HTC Wildfire" or "Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 mini" firmware on "Samsung Galaxy Pocket"?

Tags: device-firmware

Can I install "HTC Wildfire" or "Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 mini" firmware on "Samsung Galaxy Pocket"?

Hello, I want to installdifferent manufacturer's firmware on my Samsung Galaxy Pocket.

**Samsung Galaxy Pocket specs:**
http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_pocket_s5300-4612.php

**HTC Wildfire specs:**
http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_wildfire-3337.php

**Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 mini specs:**
www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_x10_mini-3125.php

Is it possible to install any official (or unoficial) firmware of these phones (HTC or Sony Ericsson) on my Samsung Galaxy Pocket?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that thing. Take in mind that each device is special and each firmware is specifically made for that device.

If you try to flash a different firmware you will brick you phone.